# Characters and symbols allowed in shipping and billing address?

Tags: street-address

What characters and symbols are allowed in shipping, billing, physical address?

**First/Last name:** Letters, space 
**Address:** Letters, numbers, space and # ' . , - /  
**City:** Letters, space and -  
**Postal:** Numbers, letters, space and -

Comment: Goofed up on step one...

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: If you're looking to standardize the address it's best to do it using an address verifying library of some sort after you let the user freely enter their address

Comment: What about non English addresses? I think you need to allow Unicode in full.

Comment: The IRS barfs on the # character in addresses.  If you use that character in your tax return address field, you'll never be able to input your address on IRS website account access forms.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the official list with [Special Characters](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c3_019.htm) NOT allowed in shipping and billing address by USPS.

Click on the hyperlink provided above and you will prompt to USPS page where you can see the **Special Characters** (not allowed), and some examples about the *preferred* and *acceptable* address format by the US Post Office.

Comment: To clarify this answer, the list of special characters that S. Mayol links to is the list *not* allowed (or often just not preferred) by USPS in shipping and billing addresses. The examples are very useful.

Comment: Thank you Neo, I added the corrections I forgot to say NOT allow.

Comment: USPS does not fix the standard especially for non US address. It's informational only if you don't use there service. I find there list unusable: removing commas and period but giving "acceptable" examples WITH commas.

Comment: In the US, the hyphen (dash) is normally only used in numbers (PO Box, etc.) but  Canada commonly has hyphenated street names. https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_023.htm

Comment: Actually, this page has a different purpose. These are instructions for address mangling when necessary to shorten an address to fit in a database field. Go up one page in the breadcrumb to see the instructions. With that context, this is actually a list of special characters to be expected in a large list of addresses.  Another page covers international addresses with non-roman letters: https://pe.usps.com/text/imm/immc1_008.htm

Answer (score 6):

Allow all of them! Especially when you take in personal names and organisations.

- Marsh & Parsons
- Apt # 5
- 651 1/2 main street
- [Westward Ho!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westward_Ho!)
- Renées Bakery
- Toys 'R' Us

If you only allow certain characters, you are only going to frustrate your end users.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the allowed characters and symbols in the billing and delivery address fields:

First and last name: Letters, space and & /. ( ) - , '

Address: Letters, numbers, space and # . , ; : ' °

City/town: Letters, space and - , . ; ' & / . ( )

Postal code: Numbers, letters and space

Phone number: Numbers, space and ( ) -

Email address: Letters, numbers and @ - _

Comment: What source did this come from?